# Android 11 ADB - deactivate "put unused apps to sleep"-option in Battery options/Background usage limits via adb

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-11, bridge

i need to find a way to deactivate the "put unused apps to sleep"-option in Android 11 via adb.
Does someone knows a way to do this?

Thank you in advance